# Can anyone give me some reference of books for absolute irreducibility over finite field?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, book-recommendation

I am looking at the book of Shafarevich. But the details about the criteria for absolute irreducibility is not there.

Comment: A polynomial that is irreducible over any field containing the coefficients is absolutely irreducible. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, a univariate polynomial is absolutely irreducible if and only if its degree is one.

Comment: What about multivariate polynomial